# Проблема с кодировкой (русский язык)

Tags: java, android, кодировка, android-sdk

Как решить проблему с кодировкой, после записи строки в файл(если текст на русском) текст становится не читабельным

```
   String outText = "мой текст";
   try {
        // открываем поток для записи
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
        // пишем данные
        bw.write(outText);
        // закрываем поток
        bw.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998929/3212712) можно принудительно указать кодировку:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter
(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sdFile), "UTF-8"));
```